# C# VSTO Powerpoint add Text as Field

Tags: c#, vsto, interop, powerpoint, office-interop

We are developing a VSTO application and we need this kind of feature group selected text as seen on the screenshot.
We are able to do it by modifying the slide1.xml of an existing powerpoint file by changing the datatype of a:fld xml tag but question is how can we do it on runtime? When the presentation is just newly opened? Thanks for the answer.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what is meant by grouping the text. The XML in the screen shot is not readable - on Stack Overflow code should be posted as text (then formatted as code).

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister. maybe can you help us if it is possible to modify xml in runtime our goal is to modify the xml data inside in the presentation in runtime we will change the type = "datetime" to another type so that we can group selection of the text. This is the link example of group selection text in PowerPoint file https://owncloud.ceetrox.de/index.php/s/tiz5cU9d30JWtXh

Comment: No, it's not possible to modify the underlying Office Open XML at runtime in PowerPoint. Only Word can do that, no other Office application.

Comment: Hi @CindyMeister thanks for the help. by the way last question can c# do a memory modification to achieve this goal? or maybe we can insert a text field not only datetime?

Comment: I won't download Office files (or any other). You'd need to explain how to create this in the UI. In a general way (although I don't know PowerPoint that well), most things that can be done in the UI can also be done using the Interop. If you can figure out how to do it in the UI and explain that, someone can probably tell you how to approach the problem using the interop.

Comment: @GirleyGonzales I am having the same problem now. Any chance you found a solution? I am thinking of somehow modifying open XML in runtime, but it feels very unreliable.
Thanks!